# Proposal merge code conflict

Tags: governance

When a proposal is published and the "core" Tezos code gets updated by a developer/team in GitLab within the 3 month voting period, could there be a scenario were the the proposed amendment code breaks and will not be compatible because of a conflict? What would happen in such a scenario? Will this just be rejected in the testing period? Or can a proposal only be done to the protocol layer and not for example the shell or network interface?